# Is uploading a file using Ruby's Net::FTP class a synchronous operation?

Tags: ruby, ftp

I am using Ruby's Net::FTP class to upload a file to a remote server.

```
Net::FTP.open(SERVER, USER, PASS) do |ftp|
  do_foo
  ftp.puttextfile(bigfile.txt, bigfile.txt)
  do_bar
end
```

Will Ruby wait for `puttextfile` to finish uploading the file before executing the `do_bar` method?

If not, how can i have this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the FTP upload is implemented as a synchronous operation meaning the next statement will be executed only after the upload has finished (or failed)

However, `ftp.puttextfile` allows to pass a callback which will get executed on every transmitted line. [Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-puttextfile)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I thought this was the case, but have been doing too much JavaScript lately.

Comment: I already expected that some javascript experience caused this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a synchronous operation.

However you can use execute the `Net::FTP.open` in a different [thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Thread.html) if you want it to happen in parallel.